# ipset - how to add all setnames to array in C, like shell command: "ipset --list -n"

Tags: c

Please show me how to add all setnames to array in C, like shell command: `ipset --list -n`
I started at https://github.com/Lekensteyn/dnsallow/blob/master/ipset.c
But I can't parse all setnames into array.

Comment: what setnames you referring ? you want to redirect out put of `pset --list -n` to an array in c ??

Comment: You could just use `popen` to run `ipset --list -n` and parse the output into your array ?

Comment: I don't like use shell script 'ipset --list -n' and parse output to C, I need to print setname by setname in C